# node module not found after copying only dependency modules with gulp-npm-dist

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp

I am trying to find the best way to package only the node_modules dependencies that my project needs. So I found gulp-npm-dist and have a gulpfile.js

```html
var gulp = require('gulp');
var npmDist = require('gulp-npm-dist');
 
gulp.task('CopyNodeDependencies', function() {
  gulp.src(npmDist(), {base:'./node_modules'})
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./node_dependencies'));
});
```

this places just the modules i need from my package.json:

```html
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "common",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-less": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-npm-dist": "^0.1.2",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "pump": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
    "chartjs-node-canvas": "^2.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0"
  }
}
```

but when I run my node file that has var moment = require('moment'); at the top it says cannot find module moment. I have renamed node_dependencies to node_modules and it still throws this error. I have also tried relative paths like ./node_dependencies/moment and that still doesnt work.

here is the folder structure of the node_dependencies if that helps:[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to leave original `node_modules` directory as is to use `require()`. 
gulp-npm-dist copies only minified files without package.json, yarn.lock etc.